# What was a reason to introduce dotted pair in LISP?

Tags: list, lisp

Does anyone know what was the historical reason to introduce a dotted pair type to LISP while existing list type covers everything?

Also I am interested in this because dotted pairs often confuse me.

Comment: Conversely, `(a b c)` is just syntactic sugar for `(a . (b . (c . NIL)))`, so why use the list notation?  I honestly don't know which came first.  Also, the list notation doesn't cover everything the dotted pair notation does; there's no list notation for `(a . b)`, for example.

Comment: Is a list notation really required for `(a . b)`? As for me (I am just started LISP learning) `'(a b)` can be used instead: they both have heads and tails.

Comment: @bananov, `(a b)` is equivalent to `(a . (b . NIL))`, which is a larger data structure indeed. If you only allow flat lists (instead of binary trees), heads and tails would need different treatment and it will significantly complicate a language (see how badly Clojure screwed it up).

Comment: @finnmw, what?!? `(a . (b . NIL))` is made of two cons cells, whereas `(a . b)` is only one cell, so `(a b)` *cannot be used*  instead of `(a . b)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Read McCarthy's 1960 paper, ["Recursive Functions of Symbolic Expressions and Their Computation By Machine, Part I"](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/recursive.html).

He starts by defining S-expressions.  One of the rules is that if e1 is an S-expression and e2 is an S-expression, then < e1 . e2 >, the dotted pair, is also an S-expression.

A few lines later, he defines the list notation, as a shorthand for an expression built up of a chain of dotted pairs.

This was the paper that first defined what would eventually become LISP.  It didn't become an actual programming language until Steve "Slug" Russell implemented the first interpreter.

Answer (score 6):

Existing *`cons`* type covers everything (list-related).  Dotted-pair notation is merely syntax for a `cons` literal.

Answer (score 3):

As you can read in the comments to your question, the dotted pair wasn't introduced next to an already existing list type; instead, it was introduced as the initial data structure, and lists are implemented in dotted pairs.

As to the question *why* the dotted pair was chosen, I believe it was guided by the hardware the original LISP system was implemented on: the IBM 704. As can be read in [the wikipedia article on `car` and `cdr`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR#Etymology), it had a 36-bit word, which could be accessed in four parts: two 15-bit, and two 3-bit parts.
With hardware like this, it's very natural to put a 15-bit address in each of the two 15-bit parts of a machine word, and voilà, you have a 'dotted pair'.

See also [the History of Lisp](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/history/lisp/lisp.html), for more information on the design of the system.

Comment: I don't think so. Pairs came from the mathematics that McCarthy was working on, not from the machine.  The cons cell is not a dotted anything; it is the machine implementation of an abstract pair.